# Using a template function with different returns for different types doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

so I wrote something like that:

```
class MyClass
{
    enum varType {INTEGER, DOUBLE, VECTOR};

    int beautiful_integer;
    double awesome_double;
    std::vector<float> many_floats;

    template <class T>
      T getVariable(varType type)
      {
          if(type == INTEGER)
          {
             return beatiful_integer;
          }
          if(type == DOUBLE)
          {
             return awesome_double;
          }
          if(type == VECTOR)
          {
             return many_floats;
          }
      }

...

};
```

But my compiler throws error "In instantiation of ..." and basically tells me that the return types don't match (and lists all of the unmatched ones, except the right one) and then tries to instantiate it with another type (for example double) and tells me that the return type doesn't match with int and vector of floats.

What am I doing wrong and how to properly write a template function in order to return different types depeneding on the parameter it was called with. For example when I call:

```
MyClass some_class(); //EDIT: this should be MyClass some_class; 
                      //thanks for pointing it out
int some_number = some_class.getVariable(INTEGER);
```

I want to assign the value of `beautiful_integer` to `some_number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template parameters are determined at compile time. You can accomplish it by template specializations. Don't use `enum`. e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
    int beautiful_integer;
    double awesome_double;
    std::vector<float> many_floats;

    template <class T>
    T getVariable();

    template<>
    int getVariable<int>
    {
        return beatiful_integer;
    }

    template<>
    double getVariable<double>
    {
        return awesome_double;
    }

    template<>
    std::vector<float> getVariable<std::vector<float>>
    {
        return many_floats;
    }

};
```

From C++17 you can also use [Constexpr If](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), e.g.

```
template <class T>
T getVariable()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    {
        return beatiful_integer;
    } 
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
    {
        return awesome_double;
    } 
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<float>>)
    {
        return many_floats;
    } 
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

then

```
MyClass some_class;
int some_number = some_class.getVariable<int>();
```

BTW: `MyClass some_class();` doesn't do what you expect. See [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/3309790).

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I didn't fully understand how to use templates like that + your solution explains all very clearly.

Comment: Also, I forgot to just write MyClass some_class; without the parenthesis. Usually my compiler reminds me ;P But the vexing parse is an interesting problem

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, with std:

```
template <class T>
const T& getVariable() const
{
    return std::get<const T&>(std::tie(beautiful_integer, awesome_double, many_floats));
}

template <class T>
T& getVariable()
{
    return std::get<T&>(std::tie(beautiful_integer, awesome_double, many_floats));
}
```

Comment: Why don't the functions return by value (as it does OP's member template)?

Comment: @水飲み鳥: I don't like returning `std::vector<float>` by value. You can still improve it by something like `typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type` instead of `const T&` in the return type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.